# onkeyup not working on hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show and hide div contents depends on the input of the user.

Here are my codes:

```
<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" onkeyup="check_input(this.value)">

<div id="repeated_pattern" style="display:none">
    <b>REPEATED PATTERN</b>
    <p>Repeated characters</p>
</div>

<script>
function check_input(value){
     //this would check if there are 3 or more characters repeated consecutively
     var repeat_pattern = /(.)\1\1/.test(value);  

     if(repeat_pattern)  { 
        $("#repeated_pattern").show(500); 
     }else{ 
        $("#repeated_pattern").hide(500); 
     }
}    
</script>
```

Tests:

1. When I try to input `gg`, the div contents did not show so the result is ok
2. When I try to input `ggg`, the div contents show so the result is ok
3. But when I try to remove the one `g` so it is now `gg`. It supposed to be the div contents must be hide but still it showing. `onkeyup` is not working properly with the `hide()` function.

How to onkeyup work with hide() or vice versa?

Comment: which browser is used

Comment: seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KjN6H/

Comment: Firefox, wait I will try it in my Chrome

Comment: nah, it's not really working. I put the output in a modal dialog. So when I input characters I then click button then see the results

Comment: It working fine in firefox as well as chrome

Comment: can you create a fiddle to demo the problem

Comment: the fiddle is working in firefox also

Comment: @sgeddes you're right maybe the jquery is the problem. I have lots of jquery defined here and I can't modified it because it is built-in on the template

Comment: @Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Is there other way that can make the div contents show or hide instead of onkeyup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: check_input is not defined
```

Try setting up the event handlers in Javascript so they are in scope:

http://jsfiddle.net/vHREF/1/

Javascript:

```
// Event handlers
if(document.addEventListener)
document.getElementById('pass').addEventListener('keyup',check_input,false);
// Good old Internet Explorer event handling code
if(document.attachEvent)
document.getElementById('pass').attachEvent('keyup',check_input);

function check_input() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //this would check if there are 3 or more characters repeated consecutively
    var repeat_pattern = /(.)\1\1/.test(value);

    if (repeat_pattern) {
        $("#repeated_pattern").show(500);
    } else {
        $("#repeated_pattern").hide(500);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
I'm trying to show and hide div contents depends on the input of the user. Here are my codes:
<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass">
<div id="repeated_pattern" style="display:none"> <b>REPEATED PATTERN</b>

    <p>Repeated characters</p>
</div>
```